# how to update value in mysql if value is not null

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table which is login, the table has two attributes, userId and loginDate
What i want to do is when a user logs into my website is to to show him his last login date

If this is the first time the user logs in meaning that the loginDate value is null i just want to insert the current date and if the user already has logged in before i want to update the date. How would i do this? so far i have this right now

```
  //..
  $userId = $_POST['the_user'];
  $query = "SELECT * 
            FROM login";
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query); //we make the query

     if(empty($row[1]){  // THIS IS WHERE I INSERT A DATE IF THIS IS THE FIRST
                             // TIME A USER LOGS IN 
        $query = "INSERT INTO login(userId,loginDate)
                    VALUES ('$userId',CURDATE())";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query); //we make the query
      }
          else if{ // THIS IS WHERE I WOULD DO MY UPDATE 



          }
```

Comment: are you *inserting* a new record on the log, or are you *updating* the value stored in the log? I recommend you create a table to store *every single login*, and then use SQL to retrieve the last login date

Comment: your select query is incomplete, you don't filter by $userid. Then about the update, just run an update query and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
INSERT INTO login (userId, loginDate) VALUES ('$userId', CURDATE())
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE loginDate = CURDATE()
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

You also need to use binded parameters to prevent against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Without changing what you've already done

```
else {
    mysqli_query($db, "update login set loginDate = curdate() where userId = '$userId'");
}
```

By the way, to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks you *really* should be using prepared statements instead of variable interpolation in strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
COALESCE
```

is the solution. Its like equivalent to Oracle's NVL.
You can use it like below in a prepared statement using parameters

```
UPDATE
    tbl_cccustomerinfo
SET
    customerAddress = COALESCE(?,customerAddress),
    customerName =  COALESCE(?,customerName),
    description =  COALESCE(?,description)
WHERE
    contactNumber=?
```